# Where can I find Durarara!! Vol 1 novel in Japanese language?

Tags: merchandise, durarara

After watching the anime, I just wanted to read the novels for a better understanding of characters and of course, it had to be in Japanese language since I am learning it.

I tried searching for it, but couldn't find. Instead, I found those in translated version.

Can anyone please tell me where I can find it?

Comment: Precaution: you probably won't find the Japanese novel freely available, and we don't encourage piracy here. Is it okay for you to pay for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to purchase the Japanese version of a light novel volume, manga volume, or anime disc that was released relatively recently, Amazon Japan is almost sure to have what you're looking for.

Since you know at least some Japanese, you can just search the site for it. Unless you want to use a proxy-shipping service, you will want to find products that ship internationally, which you can do by filtering your search down to "AmazonGlobal対象" products. Upon doing so, you will find that a print version is available [here](https://www.amazon.co.jp/%E3%83%87%E3%83%A5%E3%83%A9%E3%83%A9%E3%83%A9-%E9%9B%BB%E6%92%83%E6%96%87%E5%BA%AB-%E3%81%AA-9-7-%E6%88%90%E7%94%B0%E8%89%AF%E6%82%9F/dp/404866848X/), and also that a Kindle version is available [here](https://www.amazon.co.jp/%E3%83%87%E3%83%A5%E3%83%A9%E3%83%A9%E3%83%A9-%E9%9B%BB%E6%92%83%E6%96%87%E5%BA%AB-%E6%88%90%E7%94%B0-%E8%89%AF%E6%82%9F-ebook/dp/B00O4QK3IU), which may be cheaper overall. (But note that I've had issues with Kindle purchases from Amazon Japan - the various country-specific versions of Amazon don't share information about your Kindle purchases with each other, which seems to cause problems with some Kindle devices/apps.)

Depending on what country you live in, there may be other options that are cheaper, more convenient, or both. For example, if you reside in the US, Kinokuniya USA will ship basically any anime-related thing to you (more convenient), but charges a fairly hefty markup for it (not cheaper).

*Durarara!!* and most other light novels are generally unlikely to be found for free from any legitimate vendor, though occasionally the publishers will upload the first chapter or two online for free as a sampler.